# libc6 dependency mismatch in Debian 9.12 stretch

Tags: debian, dependencies

I have the following libc6 dependency problem in Debian 9.12 stretch.

sudo apt install libc6-dev

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.24-11+deb9u4) but 2.27-6 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.24-11+deb9u4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT1:
apt policy libc6

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.27-6
  Candidate: 2.27-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-6 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24-11+deb9u4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     2.24-11+deb9u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

EDIT2:

```
sudo apt install libc6/stable libc6-bin/stable locales/stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Release 'stable' for 'libc6' was not found
E: Unable to locate package libc6-bin
E: Release 'stable' for 'locales' was not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got help in another forum:
https://serverfault.com/a/1004951/302842

This was the solution to downgrade the problematic packages:

```
apt install libc6/stretch libc6-dev/stretch libc-dev-bin/stretch libc-bin/stretch locales/stretch sudo/stretch
```

The downgrade was successful!

Answer (score 2):

The version of `libc6` currently on your system is newer than the version in Debian 9, and that prevents you from installing `libc6-dev` (which has to match the version of `libc6`). To install `libc6-dev`, you’ll have to downgrade `libc6` and related packages:

```
sudo apt install libc6/stretch libc-bin/stretch locales/stretch
```

This might require downgrading other packages too.

Once all that’s done, you’ll be able to install `libc6-dev`.

Comment: Debian 9 is `oldstable` instead of `stable` since last July.

Comment: Added EDIT2. Unfortunately not successful. See the errors.